# Парсинг видео с канала Youtube (Python, BeautifulSoup, requests)

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть вот такой код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

ycid = input('Введите код-идентификатор канала: ') #получение идентификатор канала

url = f'https://www.youtube.com/channel/{ycid}' #создание ссылки на канал
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 7.0; Win32; x32) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'}
print(f'Парсим с канала: {url}')
html = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS )
html = html.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

div_tags = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer', 'id': 'dismissable'})
print(div_tags)
a_tags = [div.find('a') for div in div_tags]
print(a_tags)
url_img = [a['href'] for a in a_tags]
print(url_img)
```

Код должен парсить первое видео с указанного канала, но он выдаёт пустые списки.

Итог:

```
Введите код-индитификатор канала: UCviSYAcwdnDX1UoRzAHYgNg
Парсим с канала: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCviSYAcwdnDX1UoRzAHYgNg
[]
[]
[]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить код?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рассмотри некоторый канал. Просмотрим код страницы при помощи Ctr + U

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если мы выполним поиск по названию какого то видео, то мы заметим что он присутствует в коде, но не в виде HTML. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Дело в том что BS видит код, таким как он был до выполнения всех скриптов и.т.п., что может отличаться от html кода в средстве отладки вашего браузера. Вы можете получать r.content а далее про помощи json парсера выуживать информацию. В принципе ссылки на видео получить и без использования этого метода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как вы новичок то я бы порекомендовал использовать связку Selenium + geckodriver + BeautifulSoup. Selenium зайдёт на страницу, выполнить javascript-ы и выгрузит полученый html - код в BS.
 Каждое видео это отдельный ytd-grid-video-renderer c классом "style-scope ytd-grid-renderer"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Название видео содержится в атрибуте title тега  с id = "video-title"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В href содержится ссылка без домена (/watch?v=HQxZaeGxwQs)

Пример кода:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

URL = "" #Ваш урл

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(10)  #Можно ждать до загрузки страницы, но проще подождать 10 секунд, их хватит с запасом
html = driver.page_source
```

Теперь в переменной html код нашей страницы. Найдём в нем все видеоролики и названия к ним:

```
soup = BS(html, "html.parser")
videos = soup.find_all("ytd-grid-video-renderer",{"class":"style-scope ytd-grid-renderer"})
for video in videos:
   a = video.find("a",{"id":"video-title"})
   name = link.get_text()
   link = "https://www.youtube.com/" + a.get("href") 
   print(name, link)
```

Аналогичный вопрос: [тыk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121646/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be-%d1%81-%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b0/1122033#1122033)